# Seeking Clarification on an Inequality Involving Roots and Products

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, holder-inequality

#### Question

If $a_j\gt 0$, $j=1,\ldots,m$ and $x_i\ge 0$ $i=1,\ldots,n.\;$ then prove that

\begin{align}
\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left[a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right]}&\ge\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i)}\\
&\ge\prod_{i=1}^{n}\prod_{j=1}^{m}\sqrt[mn]{a_j+x_i}.
\end{align}

**What do i do so far**

I start with the left inequality

$\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left[a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right]}\ge\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i)}$

For any positive Integers

$\sqrt[k]{a_1 \cdot a_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot a_k} \ge \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_k}{k}$

Let K=M

$\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left[a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right]}$

By AM-GM INEQUALITY

$\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left[a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right]} \ge \frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_m + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{m}$

Right hand inequality $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(a_1+x_i + a_2+x_i + \ldots + a_m+x_i))$ use properties of summation $(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i))$

$\frac{a_1 + a_2 + \ldots + a_m + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i}{m} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{m}\sum_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i)$

Comment: Don't try to fit your whole question in a title, but don't leave it partial, either. Just aummarize and ask the question in the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right inequality it's just AM-GM:
$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i)}
\ge\sqrt[n]{\prod_{i=1}^n\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i)}}=\prod_{j=1}^{m}\sqrt[mn]{a_j+x_i}.$$

The left inequality it's just Holder:
$$\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\left(a_j+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i\right)}=\frac{1}{n}\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}\sum_{i=1}^n(a_j+x_i)}\ge\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt[m]{\prod_{j=1}^{m}(a_j+x_i)}.$$